# Acessing parent observableArray from child observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observableArray of `posts`. Each post should have its observableArray of comments, which i'm doing this way:

```
self.posts.subscribe(posts) {
 ko.utils.arrayForEach(posts, function(post) {
  post.comments = ko.observableArray()
 })
}
```

So I have two foreachs:

```
<!-- ko foreach: posts -->
 <div class="post">
 ...
  <!-- ko forech: comments -->
   <div class="comment">
    <span class="delete_comment" data-bind="click: $root.deleteComment"></span>
   </div>
 <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

In my viewmodel, the `deleteComment` function:

```
self.deleteComment = function(comment) {
//ajax..
// now i should remove this comment from the comments array
}
```

The problem here is that I just can't find a way to remove the comment from the comments array. I can't access the comments array from the viewmodel since it's dynamically created. I tried to bind the parent in the data-bind:

```
<span class="delete_comment" data-bind="click: $root.deleteComment.bind($parent)"></span>
```

But there's no difference, the first argument in `deleteComment` is still the comment object. How can I access the outer observableArray from inside `deleteComment`?

Answer (score 0):

> But there's no difference, the first argument in deleteComment is still the comment object.

Your `bind` changed what `this` is in the `deleteComment` function, not what the first argument is. If you don't need `this` for something else in `deleteComment`, you're good to go — use `this.comments`.

---

Or, of course, make the posts responsible for deleting their comments, rather than the root model.

Comment: Oh! That's right, it's my bad for not understading the bind concept right. Thanks!